# Git rebase caused pull request to fail in automatic merge

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a feature on branch B in my fork and I used rebase strategy to get master branch changes to B.

Today I faced a situation where after rebasing master to B (there was no changes to B from upstream), I had to push those changes to my fork forcefully (here a normal push was failed).

Then I created a pull request from my B to Master repos B where other developers also work, however the created pull request is not able to merge automatically.

What is the best way to handle these kind of situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Talk to your peers.**

You just rewrote history, so I wouldn't expect your remote branch to be able to merge automatically.  This is also why you had to force-push the branch.

Here's the scenario.  Suppose that `master` had 3 new changes on it.  The history looks something like this:

```
new3 *  * branchWork2
new2 *  * branchWork1
new1 * /
base *
```

Upon doing `git rebase master`, your history is now this:

```
branchwork2' *
branchwork1' *
new3         *
new2         * 
new1         * 
base         *
```

You haven't lost any of the work from your branch, but they're not *quite* the same commit; they're going to produce a different SHA.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem if no one has based their work off of yours, which is *generally* the scenario if you look to rebase your work against a common branch.  If someone *has*, however, now they have to reconcile what work they've done against the *old* history with the *new* history that you've pushed, which creates a headache.

In this scenario, be sure to coordinate and talk to your peers to ensure that they are both aware of the scenario and in a decent-enough position to be able to rectify any convoluted merge conflicts.

Comment: Adding to this, **avoid using rebase for branches that others work on** is a useful maxim to remember. If your branch is shared by others, rebasing would change git history, which would mean that they will have a different git history compared to that of your's on the same branch.

Comment: @Kashyap Are you suggesting to use merge over rebase for these kind of situations?. In that case we'll loose linear commit history?

Comment: @apremalal:  Again, it's a shared branch, so you can't arbitrarily decide to rewrite its history.  You can do this on your own branches *much* safer, since you won't inconvenience anyone else.

Comment: @Makoto That's true. But what is the best way to develop a feature collaboratively?. Is it "merge" that we should in these kind of situations?

Comment: Yes.  Treat it as an integration branch and merge work to it.